# i need help passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c

I tried compiling this code but its giving me "passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]". Can someone tell me what i need to do.

```
struct Book
{
char title[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH+1];  
char author[MAX_AUTHOR_LENGTH+1]; 
int  year;                       
};
void menu_delete_book(void)
{
char temp[300]; 
int x,b;
int no_books;
fgets(temp,MAX_TITLE_LENGTH,stdin);
{
for(x = 0; x< no_books; x++)
    {
    if (strcmp (book_array[x].title, temp) == 0)
        {
        for(x=1; x < no_books -1; x++)
            {
            for(b = x + 1; b < no_books; b++)
                {
                strcpy(book_array[x].title, book_array[b].title);   
                strcpy(book_array[x].author, book_array[b].author);
                strcpy(book_array[x].year, book_array[b].year);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
no_books++;
```

Comment: Note that `fgets` retains the newline from the input buffer, so you should [remove that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) before storing and comparing.

Comment: Book::year is an integer, not a string, so `book_array[x].year = book_array[b].year` should work just fine.

Comment: @John the proper way to thank is to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's complaining about this line:

```
strcpy(book_array[x].year, book_array[b].year);
```

Book::year is an integer, not a string. Do this instead:

```
book_array[x].year = book_array[b].year;
```

The warning is telling you that the integer values you were passing to `strcpy` were being implicitly converted to pointers. It's almost always an error to convert `int` to `pointer` and in your case, the integers definitely don't contain valid pointer values.